# Emacs org-mode - format source block

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to get org-mode to use indentation rules of the specified language? For example, if I have the code below, I'd like `var x;` to indent properly when I hit the tab key (just as it would in javascript mode).

```
#+BEGIN_SRC javascript
function foo() {
var x;
}
#+END_SRC
```

I have set `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)` which has enabled syntax highlighting, but not code formatting.

Comment: Formatting should be okay if you hit `C-'`. Is this no option for you?

Comment: @Tobias That actives another pane which is not as convenient, especially if I already have another buffer open there. I'd like to be able to do the same thing inline if that's possible.

Comment: I get correct indentation when hitting TAB inside the source block. Only comment is that the whole block is indented 2 spaces.

Comment: If I set the option `org-src-fontify-natively` to `t` indentation works, but after indentation point jumps back to the first line of the source block. org-version gives `8.2.5h`.

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment I meant `org-src-tab-acts-natively`. See the answer below. The jumping of the point was caused by my customization. The indentation works if I start emacs with the option `-Q`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customize the option `org-src-tab-acts-natively` to `t`. With this setting <kbd>tab</kbd> works as you expect it in the source code block. The additional indentation by two spaces is removed if you tangle the source code block or edit it with <kbd>C-c '</kbd>.
My `org-version` is `8.2.5h`.

Comment: Thanks. This works and it's what I was looking for. I had to disable `yas-minor-mode` though because I was getting: `yas--fallback: yasnippet fallback loop! This can happen when you bind `yas-expand' outside of the `yas-minor-mode-map'.`

Comment: At least for org 8.x, it seems that `org-src-tab-acts-natively` requires `org-src-fontify-natively` to also be set, or else it has no effect. The yasnippet error is being looked at: [yasnippet #761 - Conflict with org-src-tab-acts-natively](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/761).

Comment: I believe the keycombo is now `C-c '`.

Answer (score 1):

In spacemacs `org-edit-special` will open a new buffer with the right mode for regular formating key combos.

<kbd>C-c '</kbd> brings up the new buffer

<kbd>SPC m f l</kbd> formats my new buffer (clojure major mode)

<kbd>, c</kbd> exits with save.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Source language block-mode specific indentation will happen if you adopt poly-org-mode, defined in [Polymode](https://polymode.github.io/).

But wait.  There's more!

So will other language mode-specific feature (syntax-highlighting, REPL evaluation keyboard shortcuts, paren-balancing, code-navigation, etc).

I've used it on-and-off for many years, over which time it has rubbed out most idiosyncrasies and I now whole-heartedly endorse it and use it every day.  I never use org-edit-special any more (control-').